# Link Font Will Not Change

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, styles

The links in my footer will not change their color to white. I have tried setting the text decoration to none and using inline block. I have tried everything I think would work and everything that I know wouldn't work, from different shades of white to the overflow being hidden. Help with an explanation would be greatly appreciated. The code is below. Thank you.

CSS

```
   /*Footer*/

  .foot {
      background-color: #262626;
      width: 100%;
      padding: 40px 0px;
  }
```

BODY

```
 <footer class="foot">

 <p style="color:white; text-align:center; text-decoration: none; ">
 <a href="">Home</a> &emsp; 
 <a href="">Contact</a> &emsp; 
 <a href="">About</a> &emsp; 
 <a href="">FAQ</a> </p>

  </footer>
```

If needed I can provide more code from the document upon request.

Comment: Why would the text turn white? You have an empty `<p>` tag as the only thing styled to be white.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Trying setting the `a` tag color to white in your css. Boom.

Also for advice I would just get rid of the `p` tag and those inline html styles, instead put `text-align: center;` in the css. Also I would get rid of those html spaces and just add `margin-right` to all `a` tags except the last one. Just better to keep styles separated from HTML. Example below:

```css
.foot {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #262626;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 40px 0px;
}

.foot a {
  color: #fff;
}

.foot a:not(:last-of-type) {
  margin-right: 15px;
}
```

```html
<footer class="foot">

    <a href="">Home</a> 
    <a href="">Contact</a> 
    <a href="">About</a> 
    <a href="">FAQ</a>

</footer>
```

Comment: Haha thank you so much! I completely blanked .foot a! I feel so dumb. Thanks for the quick response.

Answer (score 1):

```
.foot a{
color:#fff;
}
```

Links must be defined in the a tag to change the color.

Or to change them seperately:
FAQ

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the color to the tag `a` not `p` because whatever you set on `p` will get override by the `a` properties